# SQL Round Function

Tags: sql, rounding

`round(45.923,-1)` gives a result of 50. Why is this? How it is calculated?

*(sorry guys i was mistaken with earlier version of this question suggesting value was 46)*

Comment: It gives 50 on MySQL 5.0.67-0ubuntu6, as described in http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_round - what are you using?

Comment: dude ...i knw this but why?
how it is calculated

Comment: Perhaps some more information about what you are trying to do is in order? This is incorrect information on it's own.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The SQL ROUND() function rounds a number to a precision...

For example:

round(45.65, 1) gives result = 45.7

round(45.65, -1) gives result = 50

because the precision in this case is calculated from the decimal point. If positive then it'll consider the right side number and round it upwards if it's >= 5, and if <=4 then round is downwards... and similarly if it's negative then the precision is calculated for the left hand side of decimal point... if it's >= 5

for example round(44.65, -1) gives 40
but round(45.65, -1) gives 50...

Comment: In your question round(45.923,-1) will yield 50.. however round(44.923, -1) will yield to 40.

Comment: Simillarly round(45.923,-2) will yield .00

Answer (score 4):

ROUND(748.58, -1) 750.00

the second parameter: Lenght, is the precision to which numeric_expression is to be rounded. length must be an expression of type tinyint, smallint, or int. When length is a positive number, numeric_expression is rounded to the number of decimal positions specified by length. When length is a negative number, numeric_expression is rounded on the left side of the decimal point, as specified by length.

[From](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175003.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

It is expected to be 50.

**round(45.923, 0) => 46**

expl: the last non-decimal digit is rounded (5), the desicion is based on the next digit (9)
9 is in the high half, ergo 5 is rounded up to 6

**round(45.923, 1) => 45.9**

expl: the first decimal digit is rounded (9), the desicion is based on the next digit (2)
2 is in the low half, ergo 9 stays 9

**your case:**
round(45.923, 1-) => 45.92

expl: the secon-last non-decimal digit is rounded (4), the desicion is based on the next digit (5)
5 is in the top half, ergo 4 is rounded up to 5, the rest of the digist are filled with 0s

Answer (score 2):

As for how, start by considering how you'd round a (positive) float to the nearest integer. Casting a float to an int truncates it. Adding 0.5 to a (positive) float will increment the integer portion precisely when we want to round up (when the decimal portion >= 0.5). This gives the following:

```
double round(double x) {
    return (long long)(x + 0.5);
}
```

To add support for the precision parameter, note that (for e.g. `round(123456.789, -3)`) adding 500 and truncating in the thousands place is essentially the same as adding 0.5 and to rounding to the nearest integer, it's just that the decimal point is in a different position. To move the radix point around, we need left and right shift operations, which are equivalent to multiplying by the base raised to the shift amount. That is, `0x1234 >> 3` is the same as `0x1234 / 2**3` and `0x1234 * 2**-3` in base 2. In base 10:

```
123456.789 >> 3 == 123456.789 / 10**3 == 123456.789 * 10**-3 == 123.456789
```

For `round(123456.789, -3)`, this means we can do the above multiplication to move the decimal point, add 0.5, truncate, then perform the opposite multiplication to move the decimal point back.

```
double round(double x, double p) {
    return ((long long)((x * pow10(p))) + 0.5) * pow10(-p);
}
```

Rounding by adding 0.5 and truncating works fine for non-negative numbers, but it rounds the wrong way for negative numbers. There are a few solutions. If you have an efficient `sign()` function (which returns -1, 0 or 1, depending on whether a number is <0, ==0 or >0, respectively), you can:

```
double round(double x, double p) {
    return ((long long)((x * pow10(p))) + sign(x) * 0.5) * pow10(-p);
}
```

If not, there's:

```
double round(double x, double p) {
    if (x<0) 
      return - round(-x, p);
    return ((long long)((x * pow10(p))) + 0.5) * pow10(-p);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't for me on MySQL:

```
mysql> select round(45.923,-1);
+------------------+
| round(45.923,-1) |
+------------------+
|               50 |
+------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: You say "it doesn't" but this is the exact same result as OP

Comment: @TillKolditz OP has edited the question, earlier OP has by mistake given result as 46

Answer (score 0):

And on Sql Server 2005:

```
select round(45.923,-1)
------
50.000
```

What database are you running this on?

Answer (score 0):

one thing is in the round function first parameter is the number and the second parameter is the precision index from the decimal side.

That means if precision index is 0 it is at the first decimal, -1 means before the decimal first number, 1 means right side of the first decimal i.e second decimal

For example

```
round(111.21,0)---------> return 111
round(115.21,-1)--------->return 120
round(111.325,2)---------->return 111.33
round(111.634,1)-----------> return 111.6
```

Comment: This answer seems very similar to the accepted answer; is there something different you want to highlight to the OP?If not, it's better to vote up an already existing answer, or add a comment to one that may benefit from extra context.